# Read String json array and convert to List object

Tags: java

I have the below json string that comes from the db. I have to read the json and return the equivalent java class.
Json String:

```
{
 "Items": [
   {
     "mode": "old",
     "processing": [
       "MANUAL"
     ]
   },
   {
     "mode": "new",
     "processing": [
       "AUTO"
     ]
   }
 ]
}
```

Items class

```
public class Items {

    private String mode;
    private List<String> processing;

    public String getMode() {
        return mode;
    }

    public void setMode(String mode) {
        this.mode = mode;
    }

    public List<String> getProcessing() {
        return processing;
    }

    public void setProcessing(List<String> processing) {
        this.processing = processing;
    }
}
```

Here I am trying to read the above json string array using `ObjectMapper.readValue()` method and convert it to List.
I have tried with the below code

```
ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
List<Items> actions = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(json, Items[].class));
```

and getting the error

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "actions" (class ), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "mode", "processing"])at [Source: (String)"{
         "items":[
                {
                      "mode": "old",
                      "processing": ["MANUAL"]
                    },
                    {
                      "mode": "new",
                      "processing": ["AUTO"]
                    }
         ]
        }"; line: 2, column: 13]
```

Comment: This is not a JSON formatted string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the json itself, you can try to use this website to generate the pojo class
https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

It really helpful to know what class that you need to parse the json.
For the example that you've post, what you need is 2 classes.

This is POJO for the outer json.

```
public class ExampleObject {

    @JsonProperty("Items")
    public List<Item> items = null;

}
```

This one is for your Item class

```
public class Item {

    @JsonProperty("mode")
    public String mode;

    @JsonProperty("processing")
    public List<String> processing = null;
    
    //Dont forget to put your setter getter in here.

}
```

After that, just use your code to parse that json into new class.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Items> actions = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(json, ExampleObject.class));
```

Hope it helps, cheers